# Animated pic as a page tab icon also App "log url" and "icon url"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently i saw that a person is uploading gif's on facebook.i know that facebook blocked uploading gif then how it is possible to upload gif's???? here is the Link of page 
check this out

https://www.facebook.com/INeedAllMuslimUsers

All of you see that???? how it is possible...

Also i have another app which newly updated his Icon and logo both Gif
check this out
http://graph.facebook.com/325926390835098

```
"icon_url": "http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc7/v85005/18/325926390835098/app_2_325926390835098_821224797.gif",
   "logo_url": "http://photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc7/v85005/18/325926390835098/app_1_325926390835098_214444552.gif"
```

,

this is newly updated at facebook 
i'm wonder to know that how it is possible.if someone knew that please share the trick 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported - if there's a loophole which allows this it'll likely be closed soon and the images will be removed by Facebook - I wouldn't rely on this if I were you